# My Build Pipeline getting failed at step nuget installer

Tags: azure-devops

I am using onprimise azure devops. I am getting error at nuget installer (Use Nugget).

Err: unable to verify the first certificate

A ssl ceritificate is installed on the server machine. And we dont have internet access on the server machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For the error  “Err: unable to verify the first certificate”:

You can reconfigure the agent and add the certificate to the agent configuration.

Here are the steps:

1. Export the root CA's certificate as a **PEM format** certificate (on Windows, this is the "Base-64 encoded X.506 (.CER)" option when exporting a certificate)
2. Configure the build agent with:

   **`C:\agent> .\config.cmd --sslcacert <caCertsPath>`**

This 'caCertsPath' is the path to export the certificates.

You could use  ‘/’ or ‘\’ to add multiple PEM certificates on Windows agent.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had two agents, one running on remote machine having Windows 2016 Server and another my local machine running Windows 10.

I had this issue on one of remote machines (with Windows 2016 Server) only. I tried *`.\config.cmd --sslcacert <caCertsPath>`* as well (after downloading the root certs), but no luck.

On further analysis, I found out that it is due to agent on remote machine not being able to download latest version of NuGet. I then manually copied the latest version of NuGet (6.3.0 instead of 4.1.0) from my Windows 10 machine to the Windows 2016 server machine (as in the image below) to the agent working folder (e.g., `C:agent\_work\_tool\NuGet\6.3.0`) and the issue was resolved. (Note: I know that this is not a perfect solution, but at least it may resolve the issue.)

[image: agent cert issue]